# Combining rows of data into one with an uncommon aspect in R

Tags: r

I have this data frame that goes something similar to the following.

```
    Code    Title    Year    Number    Allocation
    1000    Jack     2001    NA        6
    1000    Jack     2002    NA        NA
    1000    Jack     2003    NA        NA
    1000    Jack     2004    113       NA
    1000    Jack     2005    NA        NA
    1001    Dave     2001    NA        19
    1001    Dave     2002    NA        NA
    1001    Dave     2003    NA        NA
    1001    Dave     2004    101       NA
    1001    Dave     2005    NA        NA
```

and so on.

The data frame like this repeats with different titles, and has a number appear in 'Number' in 2004 and 'Allocation' in 2001. 
How would I go about changing the data so it turns into something a single row of the data frame

```
    Code    Title    Number    Allocation
    1000    Jack     113       6
    1001    Dave     101       19
```

Comment: @PoGibas Not yet, i updated the question for further clarity.

Comment: @DGrayson If my solution helped to solve the problem you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(-Year) %>%
  group_by(Code, Title) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(sort(.))) %>%
  distinct()
```

or:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Code, Title) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(sort(.))) %>%
  distinct(Code, Title, Number, Allocation)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Code, Title [2]
   Code  Title Number Allocation
  <int> <fctr>  <int>      <int>
1  1000   Jack    113          6
2  1001   Dave    101         19
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text="    Code    Title    Year    Number    Allocation
                1000    Jack     2001    NA        6
                1000    Jack     2002    NA        NA
                1000    Jack     2003    NA        NA
                1000    Jack     2004    113       NA
                1000    Jack     2005    NA        NA
                1001    Dave     2001    NA        19
                1001    Dave     2002    NA        NA
                1001    Dave     2003    NA        NA
                1001    Dave     2004    101       NA
                1001    Dave     2005    NA        NA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried your method but this shows up
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `CODE` must be length 4784 (the number of rows) or one, not 2839
Does that mean I need to change my CODE column from "numeric" to something else?

Comment: @D.Grayson Does your `Code` column contain any other values as well, or is it all `1000` all the way down? My solution won't work if you have other stuff in `Code` and `Title`. Please change your question example if it doesn't fully reflect your data.

Comment: Yes it does contain other values, I mentioned that a series like this repeated with different numbers and titles but it wasn't clear enough. The data set is fairly large which is the problem.

Comment: @D.Grayson My bad. See my edited answer. All you have to add is a `group_by` before `mutate_all`

Comment: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `CODE` must be length 1 (the group size), not 0" this now shows up" using the code. Could this perhaps be a problem with a package?

Comment: @D.Grayson could be. Try restarting your R session, and only run my data and code. if it still throws an error, try reinstalling `dplyr` and try again. BTW, the error referred to `CODE` instead of `Code`, make sure you are referring to the same column. R is case sensitive.